# RecyclerView items shadow clipped when RV alpha is less than 1.0

Tags: android, kotlin, shadow, alpha, elevation

I'm working on a RecyclerView that shows in horizontal orientation a list of items.
Every item is a CardView with `elevation=8dp`. The elevation gives the items a shadow that gets cut by the RecyclerView. So to make it work I added `android:clipChildren="false"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"` so that the shadow is no longer clipped. 
Everything works fine up until the alpha of the RV changes.

The animation I use to hide RV:

```
view.apply {
            animate().alpha(0f)
                    .setDuration(300)
                    .withEndAction { view.visibility = outVisibility }
                    .start()
        }
```

...and the one to show it:

```
view.apply {
            if (visibility != View.VISIBLE) alpha = 0f
            animate().alpha(1f)
                    .setDuration(300)
                    .withStartAction { view.visibility = View.VISIBLE }
                    .start()
        }
```

**ISSUE**

As long as the `alpha` of RV is lower than `1.0` the items inside of the RV are being clipped(the shadows). As soon as the `alpha` reaches `1.0` the shadows suddenly stop being clipped and everything looks nice again.

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Same issue occurs if I set the `alpha` to a fixed value below `1.0` in XML(not animating at all in this case).
Also the same issue occurs when I try to animate `alpha` of items inside the RV.

**When RV `alpha = 1.0`**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1cun1jqv0op0qw/Screenshot_20190423-180952__01.jpg?dl=0

**When RV `alpha = 0.9`**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s06f9f3orci135m/Screenshot_20190423-180819__01.jpg?dl=0

**UPDATE 1**
When I try to animate `alpha` RV parent instead of RV itself then the issue disappears. But it feels kinda hacky to have to wrap RV in extra parent just to animate its alpha :/

Comment: To draw a transparent View, Android calls `canvas.saveLayerAlpha` which creates an intermediate buffer before drawing, calls `draw()`, and then `canvas.restore()` which blends the buffer into the surface (see `View.draw(Canvas canvas, ViewGroup parent, long drawingTime)`). Unfortunately, the bounds passed to `saveLayerAlpha` are not under our control, so clipChildren is effectively true if alpha != 1. Thus, there's no 'canonical' way, only workarounds.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and have found it hard coming up with a solution. @Miha_x64 any chance you can expand on this issue?

Comment: @Jona if you need a shadow, use `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`, for example, https://github.com/Miha-x64/FiftyShades